# Monitoring performance/throughput of USB-C

Tags: usb-3, docking-station, throughput

I've got a Lenovo laptop that supports USB type-c docking and I've got a Thunderbolt 3 docking station along. **I know that this means that I'll only get the speed of USB 3.1 (gen 2)**.

Hooking up two displays through the docking station on full-HD is not a problem. When I try to hook up a third one, Windows sets all my monitors to different, lower resolutions. So technically I get the 3 displays, but not full-HD. I suspect that I've hit a limitation for USB transfer speed. Plugging one display into the laptop itself works fine, I get all 3 monitors on full-HD.

I'd like to verify my theory. Is there a tool that could measure throughput on that port while my devices are connected?

Edit:

Laptop is a Lenovo E490, the docking station is a "ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2"

Comment: It would be better to give full specifications to your dock and ask for its display limits.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, edited my post. I'm not sure that it's enough, please tell me if you need more info.

Comment: To which ports are you connecting the monitors? Which cable? Which USB-C port?